# ResultSet with variable

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Ok so basically I have this code:

```java
resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from FEEDBACK.COMMENTS");
writeResultSet(resultSet);

private void writeResultSet(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
    System.out.println("jestem w writeresultset");
    // resultSet is initialised before the first data set
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        // it is possible to get the columns via name
        // also possible to get the columns via the column number
        // which starts at 1
        // e.g., resultSet.getSTring(2);
        String id = resultSet.getString("id");
        String user = resultSet.getString("IMIE");
        String website = resultSet.getString("NAZWISKO");
        String summary = resultSet.getString("ADRES");
        String date = resultSet.getString("EMAIL");
        String comment = resultSet.getString("TELEFON");
        String opisso = resultSet.getString("OPIS");

        JTextField myOutput = new JTextField(1600);
        myOutput.setText("id w bazie danych to " + id + " imie to " + user 
            + " nazwisko to " + website + " adres to " + summary + " email to " 
            + date + " teelefon to " + comment + " opis to " + opisso);

        add(myOutput);     
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is this:

```java
resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from FEEDBACK.COMMENTS 
    where NAZWISKO LIKE " variable );
writeResultSet(resultSet);
```

I want to search by variable which is already defined, however I'm stuck and have no idea how to do it like that.

Answer (score 3):

Use `PreparedStatement`:

```
String nazwisko = ...
String query = "select * from FEEDBACK.COMMENTS where NAZWISKO LIKE ?";
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
pstmt.setString(1, nazwisko);
ResultSet rs = pstmt.execute();
while (resultSet.next()) {
    //...
}
```

In case you need to use a wildcard for your `LIKE`, choose one of these:

```
nazwisko = nazwisko + "%";
nazwisko = "%" + nazwisko;
nazwisko = "%" + nazwisko + "%";
```

Answer (score 0):

up , there are alot weird errors with your code:

like cannot find symbol variable con or incompatible type boolean cannot be converted to resultset.

I have tried this: but there is an error when executing

```
    preparedStatement = connect
      .prepareStatement("select * from FEEDBACK.COMMENTS where NAZWISKO= ? ; ");
      preparedStatement.setString(1, surname3);

while (resultSet.next()) {

    String id = resultSet.getString("i

d");
          String user = resultSet.getString("IMIE");
          String website = resultSet.getString("NAZWISKO");
          String summary = resultSet.getString("ADRES");
          String date = resultSet.getString("EMAIL");
          String comment = resultSet.getString("TELEFON");
          String opisso = resultSet.getString("OPIS");


          JTextField myOutput = new JTextField(1600);
    myOutput.setText("id w bazie danych to " + id + " imie to " + user + " nazwisko to " + website + " adres to " + summary + " email to " + date + " teelefon to " + comment + " opis to " + opisso);



         add(myOutput);
    }
```

error:
the query went fine but , the error appears here   "while (resultSet.next())"

```
 SEVERE: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jdbcexample.Main.readDataBase(Main.java:416)
    at jdbcexample.Main$7.mousePressed(Main.java:346)
```